# replacement has length zero in R from a python code

Tags: python, r, numerical-methods

I was doing numerical method in R and Python
I have applied leapfrog method in python and it worked perfectly but I want to do the slimier thing in R. Here you can see my code

Possibly I have tried doing u[2,2]=beta*(u[1,1]-2*u[2,1]+u[3,1]) this works, here I can see that the error is due to the bold statement means due to u[2,0] does not exist. But the same code worked in python, Please help to resolve the error while executing the loop

u[i, j - 1] evaluates to u[2, 0], or numeric(0). This is what produces the error.
Is there any solution.

Comment: `size` and `zeros` are not functions in base R

Comment: they worked and I have used libraries for them,

Comment: and they can be ignored this time as they are not causing any error

Comment: It does cause an error for people that try to run your code. If you are using packages make sure to include the relevant `library` calls. see how to make a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: I had added the relevant library hopefully now it runs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep in mind that R indexes are 1-based, while in Python they are 0-based. In your code, the first time through the for loop, u[i, j - 1] evaluates to u[2, 0], or numeric(0). This is what produces the error.

Comment: I have seen that thing thats why my loop is being started from 1

Comment: Yes that is the error. But how it will be resolved. The same thing u[1,-1] works in python

Comment: My requirement is to bring same results for u[2,2] in r that was u[1,1] in python. But R is causing this error

Comment: I don't understand the algorithm, so my suggestion may not be correct, but you can avoid index errors by modifying your index ranges like this:  
for(j in 2:(Nt - 1)){ 
  for(i in 2:(Nx - 1)){

Comment: Your suggstion is correct but I need those values also. I dont want to mis calculate any value. Thats why I am here asking for help ne to have each value.